# Cannot execute pytest exported from Selenium IDE Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, selenium-ide

I've created a test by recording some steps with Selenium IDE on Firefox, the latest version: 3.17.4. Then, I exported the recorded test to python (pytest). However, I cannot run it, it doesn't react. The pytest version is 7.2.1, Python 3.9 with Spyder 5.4.1 on Anaconda Navigator 2.3.2. I'm missing any package?

```
# Generated by Selenium IDE
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class TestSauceTest1():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.vars = {}
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_sauceTest1(self):
    # Test name: Sauce_Test1
    # Step # | name | target | value
    # 1 | open | / | 
    self.driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/")
    # 2 | setWindowSize | 550x680 | 
    self.driver.set_window_size(550, 680)
    # 3 | click | id=login_credentials | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_credentials").click()
    # 4 | click | id=login_credentials | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_credentials").click()
    # 5 | doubleClick | id=login_credentials | 
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_credentials")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.double_click(element).perform()
    # 6 | click | css=*[data-test="username"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"username\"]").click()
    # 7 | type | css=*[data-test="username"] | standard_user
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"username\"]").send_keys("standard_user")
    # 8 | click | css=*[data-test="password"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").click()
    # 9 | type | css=*[data-test="password"] | secret_aurce
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").send_keys("secret_aurce")
    # 10 | click | css=*[data-test="login-button"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"login-button\"]").click()
    # 11 | mouseOver | css=*[data-test="login-button"] | 
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"login-button\"]")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    # 12 | mouseOut | css=*[data-test="login-button"] | 
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element, 0, 0).perform()
    # 13 | click | css=*[data-test="password"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").click()
    # 14 | click | css=*[data-test="password"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").click()
    # 15 | doubleClick | css=*[data-test="password"] | 
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.double_click(element).perform()
    # 16 | type | css=*[data-test="password"] | secret_sauce
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").send_keys("secret_sauce")
    # 17 | sendKeys | css=*[data-test="password"] | ${KEY_ENTER}
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"password\"]").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    # 18 | click | css=*[data-test="login-button"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"login-button\"]").click()
    # 19 | click | css=*[data-test="add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack"] | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-test=\"add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack\"]").click()
    # 20 | click | linkText=1 | 
    self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "1").click()
```